# GNU Parallel argument placeholder in bash process substitution

Tags: bash, gnu-parallel, process-substitution

I have the following GNU parallel command.

```
parallel --gnu --jobs 4 \
    normalize-by-median.py \
        -k 20 -C 20 --paired -N 4 -x 6e9 \
        --out pdom-{}-diginorm.fq \
        pdom-{}.fq.gz \
    ::: 200bp 500bp 1kb 3kb 8kb
```

I would like to compress the output before writing to disk. Normally I would just pipe this to `gzip -c`, but unfortunately this particular Python script does not have the option to send output to stdout. I then thought I could use process substitution instead. I tried the following.

```
parallel --gnu --jobs 4 \
    normalize-by-median.py \
        -k 20 -C 20 --paired -N 4 -x 6e9 \
        --out >(gzip -c - > pdom-{}-diginorm.fq.gz) \
        pdom-{}.fq.gz \
    ::: 200bp 500bp 1kb 3kb 8kb
```

However, the curly braces in this latter example get interpreted literally by the subprocess, rather than as a placeholder for the GNU parallel arguments. Is there any way I can get this to work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is that >() is interpreted before GNU Parallel even starts. So you need to quote that to give it to GNU Parallel:

```
parallel --gnu --jobs 4 \
    normalize-by-median.py \
        -k 20 -C 20 --paired -N 4 -x 6e9 \
        --out '>(gzip -c - > pdom-{}-diginorm.fq.gz)' \
        pdom-{}.fq.gz \
    ::: 200bp 500bp 1kb 3kb 8kb
```

With version >20140822 you can do this:

```
parallel --plus --gnu --jobs 4 \
    normalize-by-median.py \
        -k 20 -C 20 --paired -N 4 -x 6e9 \
        --out '>(gzip > {..}-diginorm.fq.gz)' \
        {} \
    ::: pdom-*
```