# How to gzip tee output while running in gnu parallel?

Tags: gzip, gnu-parallel, tee

Suppose I am running tee inside a command executed by parallel.

I would like to gzip the output from tee:

```
... | tee --gzip the_file | and_continue
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`bash` process substitution is useful for cases like this. Something like:

```
... | tee >(gzip -c the_file) | and_continue
```

If you're choosing different files in a parallel run and need to format the name differently each time, take a look at [GNU Parallel argument placeholder in bash process substitution](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29270055/364696) for how that has to change (to defer the process substitution to act per parallel job).

Comment: If you are teeing the same output to different commands look at `parallel --tee`.